# HP Probook 4530s - fans are always on and noisy

Tags: acpi, sensors

How can I get the fans of my HP Probook 4530s to slow down when the CPU is cool?

The following attempts to fix the problem that have been unsuccesful:

- Fresh install of oneiric
- I disabled discrete graphics (radeon) : blacklisted and switched off with vgaswitcheroo
- I updated my bios to F.20 (latest on HP website)
- I disabled "Fan always on when on AC" option on the bios
- I tried to set up lm-sensors and fancontrol, but pwmconfig script returns me that "There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed" ... not very encourageing

It seems to me that the fan control worked fine in 11.04 (Natty). What has changed on 11.10 (Oneiric)?

My temperatures seem pretty correct:

```
arnaud@tool:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp2:        +47.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +33.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +46.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +25.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp6:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp7:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp8:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +44.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +44.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       -128.0°C
```

Comment: This happens on Windows too. The fans start quietly, but as soon as I start a game, or use the processors a little more, the fans become more powerful and noisy. The problem is, they never slow down.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Jupiter to tweak the power usage of your system. I have a similar issue on a Dell notebook and Jupiter is helping. The newer kernels (maybe not the newest but apparently those used in 11.10) have power usage regressions that cause low battery life and other issues with laptops. In my case, I had low battery usage and a lot of an activity. Jupiter seemed to help quite a bit:

http://liliputing.com/2011/09/how-to-use-jupiter-with-ubuntu-11-10-to-control-netbook-power-features.html

In other words, the kernel issues may be causing higher CPU usage which is reflected by your fans having to be powered on or powered on at a higher speed to combat the issue.

Update: I later took a vacuum and put it right up against my fan outlet. Everything looked cleaned before that but some fuzzy bits came out. That completely solved my fan issue although it is nice to combine both a proper solution and Jupiter.